# Adding link next to follow and share links in sharepoint online

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013, office365

I have to add a link next to follow and share links on top bar in sharepoint. So I wanted to ask if it is possible by any out of the box feature.

I have tried it using below jquery code:-

```
var newLinks = "<li class='ms-cui-topBar2'> \
   <a class='ms-cui-topBar2-a' href='http://extranet.crescent.com'>Extranet</a> \
   </li> \
   <li class='ms-cui-topBar2'> \
   <a class='ms-cui-topBar2-a' href='http://support.crescent.com'>Customer Support</a> \
   </li> ";
$('#RibbonContainer-TabRowRight').prepend(newLinks);
```

This is adding the new link but it is hiding the previous links follow and share.

Image Before running JQuery:

[image: Image Before running Jquery]

Image After running JQuery code:

[image: Image After running JQuery code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just looked at my dev environment and the '#RibbonContainer-TabRowRight' element contains anchor tags and not elements. There must be something weird with the css. Have you tried creating the actual elements?

```
var a1 = document.createElement("a");
a1.href= "http://www.google.com";
a1.innerHTML = "Extranet";
var a2 = document.createElement("a");
a2.href= "http://www.google.com";
a2.innerHTML = "CS Support";

$('#RibbonContainer-TabRowRight').prepend(a2).prepend(a1);
```

Hope that helps!